# Global Replacement for fadeIn - IE Error, jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Is there a way to do a global replacement for the fadeIn effect in jQuery to side-step the issue where fading in a transparent png in IE6-IE8 shows a distrortion?

What I mean is, I have something like this at the moment:

```
$(whichCarousel).find('ul.display li:eq(' + aSpecimen + ')').fadeIn("fast");
```

Rather than going through each function of mine that uses `.fadeIn` and doing if/else statements, is there a way in jQuery to globally say:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<9) >> find ".fadeIn" and change to ".show();"` ?
```

Comment: You could override the `show()` method so that it does the `fadeIn()` if it's a compatible browser to revert to the original `show()` if it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `show()` method so that it does the `fadeIn()` if it's a compatible browser, or revert to the original `show()` if it is not. Here's an example:

```
<button id="go">Try Me</button>
<div id="test" style="display: none">Your Content</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function($, oldMethod) {    
    $.fn.show = function() {
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1) < 9) {
            oldMethod.apply(this, arguments);   
        } else {
            $(this[0]).css("opacity",0);
            oldMethod.apply(this, arguments);
            $.fn.animate.apply($(this[0]), [{opacity:1}, {duration:1000}]);
        }
    };
})(jQuery, jQuery.fn.show);

$(function() {
    $('#go').click(function() {
        $('#test').show();
    });
});

</script>
```

You can see a demo with [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtTnM/3/). I tested in IE9 and Chrome 13 and seemed to work well.

**EDIT**

I just realized that this is sort of inefficient. It's checking the browser version on *every* call to `show()`. You might be able to do this instead (untested):

```
(function($, oldMethod) {
    if (!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1) < 9)) {
        $.fn.show = function() {
            $(this[0]).css("opacity",0);
            oldMethod.apply(this, arguments);
            $.fn.animate.apply($(this[0]), [{opacity:1}, {duration:1000}]);
        };
    }
})(jQuery, jQuery.fn.show);
```

This is such that the function is only overridden for non-IE browsers under version 9. [A jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gtTnM/4/). The original `show()` function can simply still exist.

Also, the reason for this chunk:

```
$(this[0]).css("opacity",0);
oldMethod.apply(this, arguments);
$.fn.animate.apply($(this[0]), [{opacity:1}, {duration:1000}]);
```

Is because `fadeIn()` calls `show()` at some point, and we end up with a stack overflow because of the infinite recursion. Calls to `.animate({opacity:"show"}) also call`show()`, so that didn't work either. I dug through the jQuery code to pull out the important bits to recreate the effect without causing a stack overflow.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting...how would I do that with `if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<9)`?